# Visual Studio 2013 strcpy_s and size of a word

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, strcpy, size-t

I am new to C++ and I have started to work with strings recently, but I have problems with `strcpy_s()`. In Visual Studio if I use the old `strcpy()` it said that it is unsafe and after reading  more on the internet and I found out why so I started to use no more the `strcpy()`.
In `strcpy()`, I have to tell it the size of buffer, but with this I have problems,because if I use `strlen()` it said that the buffer it is too small, even if I put `a=strlen(string)+1`,so I found out about another one called `size_t()`,and now I have no more problems with the error related to  the buffer, but I got another error.

[Error Link](http://postimg.org/image/ymeudixt3/)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int  i, size_of_word;
    char word[202];
    cin.get(word, 201, '\n');
    cin.get();
    i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(word) - 1)
    {
        if (word[i] == word[i + 1])
        { 
            size_of_word = size_t(word + i ) + 1;
            strcpy_s(word + i + 2, size_of_word, word + i);
        }
        else 
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    cout << word;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: Get rid of c-style strings and use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: strings and streams are your friend in c++. Use them when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, prefer `std::string` to char arrays, they are easier to use.

If you can't use them:

`strcpy_s` second parameter is the size of the destination buffer, whiwh is different than the size of the string.

`word` buffer size is `202`, so, `word + i + 2` buffer size is `202-i-2`, not `size_of_word`

`size_of_word = size_t(word + i ) + 1;` sets `size_of_word` to `[address of word buffer] + i + 1` which does not make any sense...

This should work (I moved buffer size to a variable to make it easier to be changed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int  i;
    static const size_t bufferSize = 202;
    char word[bufferSize];
    cin.get(word, bufferSize - 1, '\n');
    cin.get();
    i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(word) - 1)
    {
        if (word[i] == word[i + 1])
        { 
            strcpy_s(word + i + 2, bufferSize - i - 2, word + i);
        }
        else i++;
    }

    cout << word;
}
```